# Batch File: Return to caller?

Tags: windows, batch-file, return-value, return

What is the equivalent of the `return` statement for a batch file subroutine?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is:

```
goto :eof
```

This is understandably unusual for somebody accustomed to normal programming languages.

I found this info [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php).

Comment: Huh. I always assumed you had to manually define the `:eof` label at the end of your file, but apparently it's defined implicitly. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @Greg: ... wtf? Haha thanks for the info, +1. :) On a side note, do you happen to know how to break out of a `for` loop prematurely?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't know, but it probably also involves a `goto`.

Comment: @Greg: I'd think so, but for some reason, `For /L %%f In (1,1,2147483647) Do @If Not Exist "%%f" Goto :EOF` never gets out. :\

Comment: `FOR /L` loops can't break this way, all iterations are expanded (but not executed) after a `goto`

Comment: Small note: for this to work, you have to use `call :SubroutineLabelName` rather than `goto SubroutineLabelName`

Comment: As explained in the comments to [this Server Fault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/165289/how-can-i-create-multiple-numbered-copies-of-a-file-in-windows/165312#165312), the `:eof` syntax is motivated by the fact that the call to the subroutine starts a CMD subprocess treating the sub as a separate file.

Answer (score 27):

I think that it is:

```
exit /b [exitCode]
```

Not just because it is more understandeable to use, but also because exit /b (and just exit also) may return an exitCode (ERRORLEVEL) value to the caller program.

In my modest opinion, goto :eof is a strange patch that should not be used...

Comment: +1, But `exit /b` seems to be a `goto :eof` with errorlevel, visible if you try `exit /b` with `setlocal DisableExtensions`

Comment: Yes, I tested what you said (funny thing!), but my point is: If EXIT /B works and does not confuse like GOTO :EOF, why to use GOTO :EOF (or even mention it)? The explanation in the first answer above and its first two comments would not even exist if that answer would be EXIT /B

Comment: Not sure how I missed this party - I agree, EXIT /B is far better than GOTO :EOF for readability reasons (plus the added functionality). Unfortunately the batch world has been stuck on using the cryptic GOTO :EOF, and the practice propagates because newcomers see all the old examples.

Comment: @dbenham: Yes, in a way similar of using `echo.` to insert empty lines... **`:(`**

Answer (score 3):

```
Goto :Eof

Exit
```

Goto :Eof usually use in call command
such as:

```
@echo off
call :Hi
pause&exit
:hi
echo Hello!
goto :eof
```