# Rename multiple files randomly

Tags: batch-file, random, menu

I created a Menu to call this script that renames multiple text files randomly, it is only working in a .bat file alone. But it is not working in the context of the menu I created, **I believe it's something to do with looping, since it only renames the first file!** I would like someone to evaluate the situation, thank you very much already.

```
:4
cls

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do call :renameFile "%%F"
exit /b

:renameFile
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:retry
set "name="
for /l %%N in (1 1 8) do (
  set /a I=!random!%%36
  for %%I in (!I!) do set "name=!name!!chars:~%%I,1!"
)

echo if exist !name!.txt goto :retry
endlocal & ren %1 %name%.txt

)

pause
goto Menu
)

:5 < - here start the next option of menu
...
```

Comment: Not sure what 'Menu' is in the goto, but when you call a batch label, you return by using 'goto :eof:'  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728691/batch-file-return-to-caller.  Also looks like you have extra ')' characters.

Comment: Where would that apply?

Comment: Modified your script in answer below.  Not sure what the extra parens are for or why you need the pause and goto Menu calls.  Hard to say without seeing the complete file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
:4
cls

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do call :renameFile "%%F"

pause
goto Menu

:renameFile
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:retry
set "name="
for /l %%N in (1 1 8) do (
  set /a I=!random!%%36
  for %%I in (!I!) do set "name=!name!!chars:~%%I,1!"
)

if exist !name!.txt goto :retry
endlocal & ren %1 %name%.txt
goto :eof
```

The echo on the exist line is curious.  Seems like the ren could error without that.

Comment: It worked very well! But the bat file is closing after finishing! The sure thing would be for him to go back to the Menu.

Comment: Not the goto Menu makes more sense.  I updated my answer.  Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing better I see that `exit /b` is the command that makes the window close after `goto: eof` it returns to the commands from above. So, i replace `exit /b` section per:

```
pause
goto Menu
```

and now it return to my Menu

`:Menu`

Complete Code:

```
cls

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do call :renameFile "%%F"

pause
goto Menu

:renameFile
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:retry
set "name="
for /l %%N in (1 1 8) do (
  set /a I=!random!%%36
  for %%I in (!I!) do set "name=!name!!chars:~%%I,1!"
)

if exist !name!.txt goto :retry
endlocal & ren %1 %name%.txt

goto :eof
```